# Is there an AJAX Library for Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Are there any AJAX libraries for Codeigniter v2.x? Seems like Codeigniter is missing out a really useful library!

I only find AJAX/jquery libraries for the older versions of CI.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With CodeIgniter v2.x, a Javascript *driver* was introduced. I recommend looking at the user guide here: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/javascript.html

But with regards to it being a library that is useful, I think you could be misconstruing the point slightly.

There are plenty of Javascript libraries and frameworks out there to handle client-side interactivity. CodeIgniter is a server-side framework, so it cannot intermingle with a client-side framework...

So ultimately, a CodeIgniter javascript library isn't exactly needed. You accomplish everything javascript related in your view portion of MVC.

What is it exactly that you would like to do? I can maybe help/advise further if you can elaborate a bit... :)

Comment: +1, IMO the javascript drivers are totally pointless. Abstracting jQuery? Why bother - it's not abstract enough or easy to use already? It's easier to write yourself, better to put in separate files so it can be cached, and makes a lot more sense. No matter where you write CI jQuery code - it doesn't really belong there. I also don't see the drivers for other libraries coming out any time soon. The idea of portability is a joke - when do you suddenly switch javascript libraries?

Comment: Yeah I agree. I think the OP may be trying to "reinvent a more circular wheel", metaphorically speaking...